# Is LU decomposition of matrices efficient for today's standards?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, applications, matrix-decomposition

This is in the spirit of a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242786/is-the-qr-algorithm-for-computing-eigenvalues-efficient-for-todays-standards) of mine about the efficiency of the QR algorithm. The reason for asking is that I want to motivate some students, and I'm also curious.

I do understand why LU decomposition is more efficient than Gaussian elimination, but I was wondering if it is still considered efficient for today's standards, or there are different methods that are usually prefered for applications.

So, is LU decomposition still relevant in today's applications?

Comment: What is the difference between the LU decomposition and the Gaussian elimination? (I believe that for most people they are the same thing.) But yes, LU decomposition IS still relevant, but the choice of the linear solver strongly depends on the application (size of the problem, dense/sparse matrices, structured/unstructured, etc.).

Comment: This also depends on the pivoting, i.e., if you are considering the LU factiorization with the complete pivoting, with the partial pivoting, or without any pivoting at all. The last one doesn't even exist for all matrices (might not be important for some applications), and the first one is computationally quite expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Both LU decomposition and Gaussian elimination require

$$~\frac{2n^3}{3} \text{ FLOPs}$$

In fact, Gaussian elimination is LU factorization. If we start with a linear system $Ax=b$, assuming no degenerate pivots
occur, we perform Gaussian elimination on it to make it look like
$$
Ux=L^{-1}b
$$

The reason we might want to use LU decomposition over Gaussian elimination is that once we have the LU factorization of a matrix $A$, solving linear systems involving $A$ is cheap. So, if you had $n$ linear systems to solve of the form

$$
Ax=b_{k}\text{ for }k=1,2,\ldots,n
$$

this would be useful. See for example [solving linear equations on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Solving_linear_equations).

Comment: this is all true, but it does not answer the question the OP asked :)

Comment: I think it is $\frac{2n^3}{3}$, not $\frac{2n^2}{3}$.

Comment: Good catch... it was only erroneous for 4 years :/